# CWinApp global object have been called twice when start up project in vs2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, mfc

My project works normally in vs2008, when I upgrade to vs2017, it occurs the error:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!
Program: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\mfc140d.dll

File:
d:\agent\_work3\s\src\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\appcore.cpp Line: 196
  ASSERT(AfxThread() == NULL)
```

Through debug, I found that the global object: "CMyWinApp theApp" called twice.

I really dont know what happen, In my CMyWinApp.cpp, all the global object have called twice.

I check the "CMyWinApp.cpp" include, There is no other place to include it again.

I hope someone can help answer this question, thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why don't you do a search through all your CPP / H files in your project and see how many times you actually create an instance of the `CWinApp` class itself. Perhaps you are accidentally creating it in the `InitInstance`. We can't guess my friend.

Comment: Did you have a look at the call stack?

Comment: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/734033/the-global-cwinapp-object-initialized-twice-when-v.html) ; Please refer to the discussion of this link.

Comment: I have search the all CPP contains, no exceptions were found

Comment: Maybe you have some MFC extension DLLs that need to be re-compiled? Why would the error message have a path like `...\src\vctools\vc7libs\...` in it? That is highly suspicious... VC++ 2008 is version 9 of VC++ IIRC. I'd look for extension DLLs that are not using VC++2017. You can have standalone MFC libs with a different VC++ version, but not MFC extension libs.